# Testing API using frisby.js/jest with Gauge

Tags: javascript, frisby.js, getgauge

I'm trying to get gauge-js to work with Frisby. We run Functional tests on our APIs as a black-box tests using Frisby. Recently upgrade Frisby to version 2.0.8 which now use Jest. All worked good. Now I want to add Gauge-js on top to add human-readable test-specs/scenarios/steps.

I'm testing on Windows 8.1 machine:
 - [Frisby](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby)
 - [Gauge 0.9.4](https://docs.getgauge.io/index.html)
 - [gauge-js 2.0.3](https://github.com/getgauge-contrib/gauge-js)

To make it work I add Frisby as a dependency to gauge-js.
Now it partially works. It actually execute test step, but failed with

```
 ReferenceError: expect is not defined
    at incrementAssertionCount (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\gauge\plugins\js\2.0.3\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\expects.js:14:20)
    at FrisbySpec.status (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\gauge\plugins\js\2.0.3\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\expects.js:23:5)
    at FrisbySpec._addExpect.e (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\gauge\plugins\js\2.0.3\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\spec.js:396:23)
    at FrisbySpec._runExpects (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\gauge\plugins\js\2.0.3\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\spec.js:288:24)
    at _fetch.fetch.then.then (C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\gauge\plugins\js\2.0.3\node_modules\frisby\src\frisby\spec.js:142:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Here is the actual test step:

```
/* globals gauge*/

"use strict";

var frisby = require('frisby');

// --------------------------
// Gauge step implementations
// --------------------------

step("Get responds with <state>.", function (state, doneFn) {

  frisby
    .timeout(1500)
    .get('http://localhost:8001/some/get/resource', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic QWERTYASDFEDEFTGHYFVCCFRJgyuku'
      }
   })

    // .expect('status', 200)
    // .expect('header', 'Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    // .expect('json', state)
    .done(doneFn).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

When commented out lines uncommented the error occur.

I think the problem is actually with how it's load dependencies, but my js knowledge is a bit fragmented and rusty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like frisbyjs requires `jasmine-node` as its javascript runtime, whereas gauge-js uses `node`. FWIW, I get the same stacktrace on a vanilla gauge-js project with frisby.

Comment: I drilled down through the code of both stacks and got it. What I can't get my head around is how to add missing references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better solution to the original problem. When I start implementing what @duyker suggested. I noticed (finally) that Frisby code has intention to ignore dependency on Jasmine if it's not there, but has a bug. So I submit a [fix for it](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/pull/422). And it was accepted.

Now problem solved and Frisby can work without Jasmine or Jest.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the `.expect(...)` functions are undefined is that frisby is expecting that jasmine is the test runner and the `expect` function from jasmine is available for it to use.

All of frisby's included `expect` functions execute the below "incrementAssertionCount". Because it cannot find the `expect` in the `if (_.isFunction(expect))`, it is unable to provide the default expects that frisby would offer.

```
function incrementAssertionCount() {
  if (_.isFunction(expect)) { // FAILS HERE: 'expect' does not exist
    // Jasmine
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  }
}
```

There looks like there is a simple alternative, which is to copy the expect functions from frisby into your code and call the `addExpectHandler` method (even better, make an external package you can reference so you don't have to copy it into every project).

A simple example is shown below:

```
var frisby = require("frisby");
var assert = require("assert");

function statusHandler(response, statusCode) {
  assert.strictEqual(response.status, statusCode, `HTTP status ${statusCode} !== ${response.status}`);
}

beforeScenario(function () {
  frisby.addExpectHandler('status', statusHandler);
});

step("Call httpbin.org and get a teabot", function (done) {
  frisby.get('http://httpbin.org/status/418')
    .timeout(2000)
    .expect('status', 418)
    .catch(function (e) {
      done(e);
    })
    .done(done);
});
```

Comment: I dig through both stacks' code. and saw what is the problem. Kinda stuck in a tunnel and was trying to find the way to solve reference problem. Whereas you absolutely right there are no actual reason in doing so as jasmine `expect` invocation does not add value when code executed from gauge, as invocation and reporting mechanism is totally different.